# Help with row count

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help with row count. i manage to add today and total members count (rows). i want to count this week and this month. can anyone point me out how to do it? thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Members\n";

$utoday = date("j. n. Y");

$today = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mambers WHERE date='$utoday' ");
$num_today = mysql_num_rows($today);

echo "$num_today Members\n";
```

Comment: What data type do you use to store dates?

Comment: You'll need to changge that to DATE or DATETIME. They are designed for dates and date processing, varchar is not. You can find records with a specific date, but there's _no way_ you'll be able to do anything with date ranges. And you want to use ranges.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stored the date as a type date, you can use the [mysql built-in time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

For example, you can group by MONTH(date).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count for this week starting from the most recent Monday:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) WeekCount
FROM members A,
(
   SELECT
       (MondayDate + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) PastMonday,
       ((MondayDate + INTERVAL 7 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) NextMonday
   FROM 
       (SELECT DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY) MondayDate) AA
) B
WHERE date >= PastMonday AND date < NextMonday
;
```

If you want to count for this month starting from the 1st query this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) MonthCount
FROM members A,
(
    SELECT FirstOfThisMonth,
    ((FirstOfThisMonth + INTERVAL 32 DAY) - INTERVAL (DAY(FirstOfThisMonth + INTERVAL 32 DAY)-1) DAY) FirstOfNextMonth
    FROM
    (
        SELECT (DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW())-1) DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND) FirstOfThisMonth
    ) AA
) B
WHERE date >= FirstOfThisMonth AND date < FirstOfNextMonth
;
```

Give it a Try !!!